# How to view boot debugging logs BCDedit

Tags: bcd, bcdedit

To expand on the title,

Ive setup debugging of my boot sequence with the following commands:

```
bcdedit /bootdebug {bootmgr} on
bcdedit /bootdebug on
bcdedit /debug on
```

Where does BCDedit store debug logs/dump files for this action?